# pgbench invalid number of clients

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

when I try to use pgbench with more than 1000 clients it gives me "invalid number of clients" so how to increase this number ?

```
postgres@test_db:/root$ pgbench -t 1000 -c 10000 -S pgbench_test -C -n -p 5433
invalid number of clients: "10000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade.  In version 12, the limit is determined dynamically based on `ulimit -n`.

Upgrading will allow you do break you system more elegantly.  You can even use a newer pgbench against an older server (or older pgbouncer), if you want.

Comment: You made my day many thanks to you, I didn't upgrade due to business reasons but I installed it in parallel and it did the job perfectly